# Azure CLI - How to create a new client secret with a specific "Description"

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

I used this command to create a client secret,

```bash
az ad sp create-for-rbac  -n my_app --years 99
```

but I found this command will create a new secret named "rbac" to override the old secret as below.

[image]

**I want to create a new secret** with a specific "Description", but I have not found any way in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create) to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran the same command as you and got same response with **`rbac`** in **Description** like below:

```bash
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n my_app --years 99
```

[image]

To get these results from **Azure CLI**, you can use below command:

```bash
az ad app credential list --id <ApplicationID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To create a **new secret** with a specific **"Description"**, you can make use of below command:

```bash
az ad app credential reset --id <ApplicationID> --display-name <Enter description here> --append
```

I ran the above command and created **`new secret`** with description.

When I tried to list the secrets of that application, I got both **client secret details** successfully like below:

```bash
az ad app credential list --id <ApplicationID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Azure Portal, I can see the new client secret with **description** like below:

[image]